# Что именно я должен изучать дальше

Tags: c++

Я изучил базу C++ , знаю синтаксис ,знаю в целом как писать код ,т.е как создавать классы наследовать , циклы и т.д  Но что дальше делать я вообще не понимаю , хочу на практике написать что нибудь простое , но без понятия , все программы пишутся используя уже готовые сторонние библиотеки?

Что именно я должен изучить что бы начать писать программы , понимаю что для разных программ нужны разные знания в разделах C++ ,но мне бы понять с чего начать хотя бы.

Я сделал уже больше 100 задач на циклы , создания классов наследования ,виртуальные классы ,абстрактные классы. А на практике где это применить.

Comment: "А на практике где это применить"  --- устройтесь на работу и сразу найдётся 1002398 мест где что применить

Comment: Найдите в сети пример тестового и попробуйте его выполнить. Второй вариант, попытайтесь пройти собеседование. Сразу же узнаете в чем могут быть пробелы.

Comment: Подключитесь к базе данных и заполните ваши собственные классы данными из базы, выведите на экран в отсортированном виде

Answer (score 1):

Сам недавно столкнулся с таким вопросом, понимаю Вас) Я поступил так: codewars помог вспомнить алгоритмы и тп. Выбрал самое важное: потоки, синхронизация потоков, асинхронность, сеть. Написал простенький чат используя select(что кстати оказалось позже на одном собеседовании). Потом пошел в Qt и написал простенькое приложение для работы с заметками и повторением их. А там и стажировка на qt и последующий инвайт. Сейчас штрудирую ANSI и отвечаю на вопросы на SO. Так и пригодилось всё) Если просто нужны таски, напишите коммент, подкину идей по интересующим Вас направлениям)